# Edit PDF file programmatically

Tags: android, pdf

Currently I have written an Android app that can open a PDF file using default PDF viewer in android and send it through mail.

Is there any way in android through which I can edit PDF from my app?

Comment: I don't know what you are up to but yes you can edit,read,write it by using itext library for android i have did not edit any pdf but i have write and view it with this library

Comment: `quoppa` library might be useful to you

Comment: *edit PDF* - what exactly do you want to do? There are certain things you can easily do to a PDF (e.g. adding or filling form fields, adding new pages with new content) and there are certain things which are really difficult (e.g. changing existing text content and expect paragraph or page reflows).

Comment: I want to add my text in form fields. I have name,address etc. fields in pdf form, so user can open form using my app,edit it and save it.

Comment: @NevilPatel Did you any solution? As I want to achieve same thing as yours!