# Kotlin : Edit a pdf programmatically or an html

Tags: android, html, pdf, kotlin, html-to-pdf

I have developed an application in Android using Kotlin.

I am making a pdf from an html string. The pdf(and the html) is showing a conversation like this:

[image]

Of course the conversation have an unknown length. I use PdfConverter and I take the html as a pdf
and this is the point. I take as an output a pdf with conversations of some pages.

My question is how could I take as a result a pdf with the conversations I have but at the end of 
each page I want to be written the number of the page and a note.

So this is what I thought :

**1)** If I could firstly make the pdf with the conversation as I made it and the edit the pdf programmatically to add the number of page and the notes at each page. 
I was looking to implement this solution and I found only this :

[Edit PDF file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934346/edit-pdf-file-programmatically)
I have to say that I am not looking for paid libraries or something. Because in my search
I found one solution with paid library.

**2)** The second thought is to add the page number and note at each page to the html.
The case here is, given an html for which is unknown how many pages will produce if It would be converted to a pdf. Also the position in which the page is ending is a question, where it is.

I want an advise about which way should I follow(even if it not one of the 2 I described), from your experiences and I will come back with new question more specific.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the end what worked for me is the following approach with PDFBox :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_adding_text.htm

https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

With these I added text to each page of an already existed pdf.